# Generate a collection of dates from an objects collection

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have a collection of objects:

```
private ObservableCollection<ObjectClass> myObjectsCollection;
```

It contains several properties which one of them is `Date`:

```
public string Date { get; set; }
```

The collection may contain several objects with a same date.

I want to generate a new `ObservableCollection` which holds a new objects from the same class of `ObjectClass` but every object represents only one date.

For example: Let's say I have 1000 objects which holds a total of 14 dates across the whole collection. So the new collection will hold only 14 objects of the same class type. Every new object will contain only `Date` property.

Comment: How do you populate this collection?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to group collection of ObjectClass by data and take first:

```
myObjectsCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.First())
```

Comment: Hello, no. For example: Let's say I have 1000 objects which holds a total of 14 dates across the whole collection. So the new collection will hold only 14 objects.

Comment: What should contain each of this 14 objects? Which object you want to choose, if you have two ObjectClass for the same date

Comment: A `Date` property

Comment: Which object you want to choose, if you have two ObjectClass with the same date?

Comment: My solution should suit for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129725/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-axcelenator).

Comment: Now I can get a good list. But, the newList is not an Observable Collection of the same type as the old one.

Comment: You can do: new ObservableCollection<ObjectClass>(myIEnumerable);

Comment: I'm sorry but my C# is not so good. What should I put instead myIEnumerable?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a collection of some type, this type has a field called `Date`, this collection might have objects with same date. for example if your collection has 100 items and 50 of them have same date, you need to write a query that gives you 50 items instead of 100. In this case as @Victor Leontyev answered you just need to group by the items based on the `Date` property:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

var list = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 5, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 5, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 5, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 5, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 6, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 6, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 2, 12) });
list.Add(new MyObject { Date = new DateTime(2015, 2, 12) });

var newList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Date);
```